# Git ignore patterns: ignore a specific directory

Tags: git

I have a git repository, with ignored paths specified in `.git/info/exclude` as they are specific to this clone.  I wish to exclude a directory `/foo` (and everything below it) which is located at the root of the repository.  However, I do not want to ignore `/foo-x` or `/y/foo`.  I have played around with ignore patterns but cannot work out how to do this.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add to `.gitignore` (for all users that will clone your repo) or `.git/info/exclude` ([only for your machine](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-ignore.html)) this:

```
/foo/
```

Note, that

> Files already tracked by Git are not affected;

by `gitignore`. So, you should `git rm` them from the repo!

Comment: Unfortunately, this also ignores `/foo-x`.

Comment: @AndrewHo I believe you're doing something wrong. I've checked it: `$ cat .git/info/exclude:` `/data/` `$ git status`: `# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# data-x`

Comment: @AndrewHo Does your foo-x contain even 1 file?

Comment: You were right.  I had the solution all along, but was careless when testing it!

Comment: Can I add, make sure to include that leading /. If you don't then git will ignore all directories named foo even if they are not in the root. I've been learning that the hard way for months now! I just figure out the problem today.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it into `.gitignore` (for all) or `.git/info/exclude` (for you)

```
foo/
```

You can end patterns with a forward slash `/` to specify a directory.